# How to do custom order on java ENUMS?

Tags: java

I have `Enum` class as

```
public enum ServiceTypes {
    Zero("zero", 6, true),
    AVL("Avl", 1, true),
    VPS("vps", 2, true),
    CALCULATOR("calculator", 3, true),
    SIMULATOR("Simulator", 4, true),
    CONTRACT("Contract Output", 5, true),
    ALL("all", 7, true);
    private static final OrderComparator orderComparator = new OrderComparator();
    private static final OrderComparator nameComparator = new OrderComparator();

    @Nonnull
    public static ServiceTypes[] getOrderedServiceTypes() {
       Arrays.sort(values(), orderComparator);
       return values();
    }

    @Nonnull
    public static ServiceTypes[] getNamedServiceTypes() {
        Arrays.sort(values(), nameComparator);
        return values();
    }

    private static final class OrderComparator implements Comparator<ServiceTypes> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final ServiceTypes o1, final ServiceTypes o2) {
            return o1.getOrder().compareTo(o2.getOrder());
        }
    }

    private static final class AlphabeticalOrder implements Comparator<ServiceTypes> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final ServiceTypes o1, final ServiceTypes o2) {
            return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I `test` `getOrderedServiceTypes()`, I see `Zero("zero", 6, true)` as the first element , which is incorrect.

Seems like `values()` is not sorted based on the comparator.

How can I run the custom orders on Enum?

Comment: consider showing all the code.  All the code will include the constructor and will show how the parameters to the constructor are declared.

Comment: as written, getNamedServiceTypes()  will only work if values() does not create a new object each time it is called.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen `values()` is an finalized enum method.

Comment: @Legend - Whoops! My bad - thanks, now I can say I learned something today :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seems like values() is not sorted based on the comparator.

Indeed. As per the specification ([section 8.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)):

> (`values[]`) Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
>   type, in the order they're declared.

Sorting the array returned by `values` *once* isn't going to have any effect - a new array will be handed out on the next call. You can do this though:

```
public static ServiceTypes[] getNamedServiceTypes() {
    ServiceTypes[] array = values();
    Arrays.sort(array, nameComparator);
    return array;
}
```

Or I would personally create an immutable list of them sorted each way you care about, and return that same list reference each time.

Answer (score 6):

No, what's happening is that `values()` creates a new array each time, so you're sorting an array of the values and then returning a *completely different array*.

All you need to do is e.g.

```
ServiceTypes[] values = values();
Arrays.sort(values, orderComparator);
return values;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another observation. You are initializing both `orderComparator` and `nameComparator` as objects of `OrderComparator`. You need to take a look at it if it's not intended.